# Im having trouble evaluating this scheme function?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I put the code in dr racket and it gave me 0 but Idk if I'm running through the code correctly

```
(let ((l (+ 2 1))(e (/ 16(* 4 4)))(t (length '(5 7)))) (if (< l e) t 0))

so what i ended up getting was (let ((l 3)(e 1)(t 2))
                                      if (3 < 1)
                                           2 = 0)))
```

Comment: `if (3 < 1)` isn't Scheme.. It's `(if (< 3 1) 2 0)` where `0` is the correct result since `(< 3 1)` is false.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, since after the let statement `l = 3`, `e = 1` and `t = 2`

Therefore the if statement of `(< l e)` will evaluate to false and output 0.